# How to know if task is private in Asana API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

What is the flag to detect that the task is private? I can't see it in Task object. Is there any way to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

We don't expose this via the API, sorry. I'll note this as an opportunity for the future.